# How to define Load balancing endpoint dynamic in wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb 4.8.1.
I wish to do dynamic  endpoint load balancing is there any option available in wso2esb.
how to provide load balancing to this proxy in endpoint level. Where as wso2 esb support endpoint level load balancing for static endpoint.

Please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697385/how-to-handle-dynamic-endpoint-load-balancing-round-robin-in-wso2-esb

Comment: You should have a look there : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199200/wso2-dynamically-adding-an-endpoint-to-loadbalance-endpoint][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20199200/wso2-dynamically-adding-an-endpoint-to-loadbalance-endpoint

Comment: Hi Can you explain this more clearly, I want to know whether ur trying to load balance multiple backend endpoints or do u want to load balance the ESB proxy endpoints that are exposed to service consumers.

Comment: Thanks for replay.I am trying for  load balance multiple backend endpoints

Comment: You can load balance your multiple backend service endpoints using the LoadBalance Endpoints available in WSO2 ESB. Refer [this](http://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Load-balance+Endpoint) documentation. Also refer [this](http://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Sample+52%3A+Using+Load+Balancing+Endpoints+to+Handle+Peak+Loads) sample.